# Sync of Employees group in AD and SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint

Sync of Employees or any other AD group and SharePoint 2007

Currently there is an employee group in both AD and SharePoint

- We need a batch script, or workflow, or anything that keeps these groups synced
- Should be a one way sync with Active Directory being the Master and SharePoint being the copy
- It should sync automatically every hour, and we should have the ability to manually perform a sync at any time
- It should NOT delete the group and repopulate it. That would mean that there would be some time where no one has access

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using using Windows Authentication on your SharePoint site?

If you are, you don't need a script to keep you groups synchronized if you do.. They will stay synchronized on their own. Removing a user from the AD group will remove it from the SharePoint group as well.

You might experience a little delay though which might be why you thought you needed a script (should take no longer than 15 minutes).

If you are in a rush, you can do an IISReset and you should see your change immediately.

---

If you are not using Windows Auth, or if your SharePoint group is a different group from the AD one, then you will need to add a synch routine.

Your best bet is probably some code (or SSIS package that runs) every x minutes. In a loop, check each member of your AD group. Validate that they are in the SharePoint group. When they aren't, use code like this :

```
using (SPWeb oWebsiteRoot = SPContext.Current.Site.RootWeb)
{
    //Loop through your AD group here
    oWebsiteRoot.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
    oWebsiteRoot.Groups["Employee"].AddUser(username, email, fullname, String.Empty);
    oWebsiteRoot.Update();
}
```

where Site is your site collection and user has all the information you need. That will create the SharePoint user and add it to the group.

When that's done, go through each SharePoint user and validate that they are in the AD group. When they aren't, remove them :

```
using (SPWeb oWebsiteRoot = SPContext.Current.Site.RootWeb)
{
    SPGroupCollection collGroups = oWebsiteRoot.SiteGroups;
    SPUser oUser = oWebsiteRoot.Users["User_Name"];

    foreach (SPGroup oGroup in collGroups)
    {
        oGroup.RemoveUser(oUser);
    }
}
```

Comment: We are using windows authorization. Profiles are setup to synchronize with an incremental import in the shared services user profile import service. We can only schedule the import/synchronize once a day using SharePoint. We would like to do it more frequently like once an hour and also the ability to do it manually whenever we need.

Comment: Then the code I gave you should do the trick. Wrap it inside a web part if you want to do it manually on demand.